# HTML5: Detecting if you're on mobile or pc with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, responsive-design, media-queries

What javascript code can I use to detect if users are on a mobile or pc/mac browser in HTML5?

Comment: but why would you ever need to do that?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I was looking into this a few years back.  In short, you can't do this with 100% reliability.  There seem to be 2 approaches commonly used to provide a 'best-guess':

**1. User Agent Detection**
This is where you check what the client is *claiming* to be. 
e.g.

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
    // is mobile..
}
```

It's not perfect, since I believe it is fairly easy for this property to be altered accidentally or otherwise.  Plus it is highly unlikely that this list will still be accurate in 2 years' / 2 weeks' / 2 days' time!

**2. Using Client Capabilities**
As you can imagine, a more pragmatic approach - allows you to cater to the known physical capability of the client. e.g.

```
if( screen.width <= 480 ) {     
    // is mobile.. 
}
```

However this is not ideal either, since higher and higher pixel densities in modern devices give you a misleading result: appearing that you have more 'room' than you actually do. Plus different browsers may expose their capabilities through different means.

If anyone has any better ideas to robustly discern between desktop and device, please comment! :)

Comment: Just to clarify: by "higher pixel density" you mean that the DPI is higher, so the pixels are smaller and packed tighter together which can lead to major usability issues on mobile devices even if the device has a "laptop resolution" of say 1024 pixels wide. Correct?

Comment: Exactly: so a device such as a tablet may report that it is "1024px wide" for example, and deceive a 'traditional' web developer like me into thinking that this translates to having the width of a typical office monitor, which may also report to be 1024px wide.