# why some website can't test responsive on desktop browser?

Tags: html, css

I have question about responsive design layout. I found that some website ex: http://www.asos.com, http://havenshop.ca. when I resize browser, it doesn't show mobile site. but when I visit by mobile, it show mobile site. and URL is changing to m.xxx.com. my question is:

1. what is this method, how can I do like this ? I mean not showing responsive on desktop
2. Are there anyway to check mobile site on desktop in case this method is applied ?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think about how your redirect actually works, in theory it's quite understandable - "If the user is using a mobile device, redirect them to the mobile version of the site". The problem is that when people visit your website, their web browser does not know whether, "I am a mobile device" or "I am a desktop computer". Instead, the browser introduces itself by providing a "user-agent", which includes the browser name, version, and other information about your operating system.

To redirect a mobile visitor, you'll need to determine if their browser is a web browser on a mobile device or not. You can determine which browser the visitor is using. You can also look at other things such as their screen resolution and whether they accept file types that are common to mobile devices. Below we've listed a few methods you can use to redirect visitors to the mobile version of your website.

Because mobile phones typically have a small screen width, you can redirect visitors to your mobile site if they have a screen width of less than or equal to 800 pixels. You place this code in the head section of your main website code. That way when your site is visited, the javascript will see the browser width and redirect to the appropriate site

You can use the following code to do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  <!--
  if (screen.width <= 800) {
    window.location = "http://m.domain.com";
  }
  //-->
</script>
```

**.htaccess URL rewrite redirects**

You can use a .htaccess redirect to transfer visitors based upon the MIME types the browser supports. For example, if the user's browser accepts mime types that include WML (Wireless Markup Language), then most likely it is a mobile device.

The code below should be placed in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
# Check for mime types commonly accepted by mobile devices
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} "text\/vnd\.wap\.wml|application\/vnd\.wap\.xhtml\+xml" [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^ http://m.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

[Reference](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/redirects/mobile-redirect)  site:

Comment: thank for ur info. and if I would like to see source code on mobile site using desktop. How can I do ? Thks

Comment: I didn't try but http://www.ampercent.com/check-site-source-code-design-mobile-theme-desktop-browser/9020/ may help you.

Answer (score 1):

In Php you can achieve it this way. for reference please check this
http://webdesign.about.com/od/mobile/a/detect-mobile-devices.htm

```
<?php if (
$ua = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
stristr($ua, "Windows CE") or
stristr($ua, "AvantGo") or
stristr($ua,"Mazingo") or
stristr($ua, "Mobile") or
stristr($ua, "T68") or
stristr($ua,"Syncalot") or
stristr($ua, "Blazer") ) {
$DEVICE_TYPE="MOBILE";
}
if (isset($DEVICE_TYPE) and $DEVICE_TYPE=="MOBILE") {
  $location='mobile/index.php';
  header ('Location: '.$location);
  exit;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It uses a concept called user-agent.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537503%28v=vs.85%29.aspx 
In a nut shell it pretty tells what your browser is and if it falls under mobile platform string it shows mobile site and if desktop they show desktop version

Answer (score 0):

You can use JS

> if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera
>   Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {    redirect to mobile version }

see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25542814/html5-detecting-if-youre-on-mobile-or-pc-with-javascript)