# How to hide Address bar of a responsive webapp when opening through mobile browser?

Tags: javascript

I have a responsive webApp which is accessible from both Web Browser and Mobile browser. I want to hide the address bar once the application loads and this will continue in every other page of the application so that it feels like an APP. Can it be achieved through Javascript?

Comment: Firs see following link to detect host device (mobile or pc): https://stackoverflow.com/q/25542814/5538979. Then set display of your address bar as `none` to hide it for mobile browser.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you are planning to add some extra config in your responsive web app, then you can do it. Take a look at [Progressive Web App](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_web_app). In this type user have the option to "Add to homescreen" for any mobile device. Then the address bar will be hidden for this kind of app.

The main thing you have to add in the Manifest.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If by 'address bar' you mean the top bar where you enter the website url, then no: you cannot modify the appearance of the browser just by javascript.

You used to be able to open a window without the address bar through javascript, but for security reasons that is no longer possible as users should be able to see on what domain they're on.

Most mobile browsers already have this kind of behaviour by the way, where they hide the address bar once you're scrolling the web page...

Answer (score 0):

You can set your website in full screen mode using this method your address bar will hide automatically.
You can set browser as full width using JQuery OR Meta Tags, Please refer [this](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/full-screen-web-apps--mobile-7509) link.

It will help you.

Thanks